# jhipster import-jdl not generating entities from jdl file

Tags: jhipster

I have created a jdl file using jdl-studio.
I tied to create entities from jdl file using jdl-import.

following is the snippet of my cmd terminal:

```
D:\spring-boot\examples\espressob>yo jhipster:import-jdl ./jhipster-jdl.jh
The jdl is being imported.
D:\spring-boot\examples\espressob>
```

***the problem***

It just prints that the jdl file is being imported, thats it. 
I have checked if it generated code for entities from the jdl file, unfortunately it did not.

---

**Env details**

**.yo-rc.json** file content :

```
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "jhipsterVersion": "3.4.2",
    "baseName": "espressob",
    "packageName": "com.iwantunlimited.espressob",
    "packageFolder": "com/iwantunlimited/espressob",
    "serverPort": "8080",
    "authenticationType": "jwt",
    "hibernateCache": "hazelcast",
    "clusteredHttpSession": "hazelcast",
    "websocket": "spring-websocket",
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "postgresql",
    "prodDatabaseType": "postgresql",
    "searchEngine": "elasticsearch",
    "buildTool": "maven",
    "enableSocialSignIn": true,
    "jwtSecretKey": "790501d7e04040394e33964a4ee715408ec0408f",
    "useSass": true,
    "applicationType": "monolith",
    "testFrameworks": [
      "gatling",
      "cucumber",
      "protractor"
    ],
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    "enableTranslation": true,
    "nativeLanguage": "en",
    "languages": [
      "en",
      "fr",
      "hi"
    ]
  }
}
```

**jhipster-jdl.jh** file content:

```
entity InsuranceCategory {
    name String required,
    description String,
    isActive Boolean,
    createdDate ZonedDateTime,
    modifiedDate ZonedDateTime,
}
relationship ManyToOne {
    InsuranceCategory{createdBy} to User
}
relationship ManyToOne {
    InsuranceCategory{modifiedBy} to User
}

entity InsuranceProvider {
    name String required,
    isActive Boolean,
    createdDate ZonedDateTime,
    modifiedDate ZonedDateTime,
}
relationship ManyToOne {
    InsuranceProvider{createdBy} to User
}
relationship ManyToOne {
    InsuranceProvider{modifiedBy} to User
}
relationship ManyToMany {
    InsuranceCategory{provider} to InsuranceProvider{category}
}

entity Policy {
    name String required,
    isActive Boolean,
    createdDate ZonedDateTime,
    modifiedDate ZonedDateTime,
}
relationship ManyToOne {
    Policy{createdBy} to User
}
relationship ManyToOne {
    Policy{modifiedBy} to User
}

relationship OneToMany {
    InsuranceCategory{policy} to Policy
}

relationship OneToMany {
    InsuranceProvider{policy} to Policy
}

dto all with mapstruct
```

Tried :

1. removing relationships with User entity -> not working
2. re arranging sequence of entries in jdl file (first all entities, then relationships) -> not working

Comment: Have you tried to import (jhipster import-jdl jhipster-jdl.jh) calling it from the same subdirectory where the file (jhipster-jdl.jh) is? (without ./)

Answer (score 0):

I try your jdl-file with jhipster 3.6.1 version and it works with the following warning:

```
$ yo jhipster:import-jdl ./jhipster-jdl.jh  
The jdl is being parsed.  
**Warning:  An Entity name 'User' was used: 'User' is an entity created by default by JHipster. All relationships toward it will be kept but any attributes and relationships from it will be disregarded.**  
Writing entity JSON files.  
Generating entities...
```

Also would recommend removing the commas at the end of the last field in the entities definitions:

```
entity InsuranceProvider {  
    name String required,  
    isActive Boolean,  
    createdDate ZonedDateTime,  
    modifiedDate ZonedDateTime  
}
```

Instead of:

```
entity InsuranceProvider {  
    name String required,  
    isActive Boolean,  
    createdDate ZonedDateTime,  
    modifiedDate ZonedDateTime ,
}
```